# How to send image data over linux socket

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a relatively simple web server I have written in C++. It works fine for serving text/html pages, but the way it is written it seems unable to send binary data and I really need to be able to send images.

I have been searching and searching but can't find an answer specific to this question which is written in real C++ (fstream as opposed to using file pointers etc.) and whilst this kind of thing is necessarily low level and may well require handling bytes in a C style array I would like the the code to be as C++ as possible.

I have tried a few methods, this is what I currently have:

```
int sendFile(const Server* serv, const ssocks::Response& response, int fd)
{
// some other stuff to do with headers etc. ........ then:

    // open file
    std::ifstream fileHandle;
    fileHandle.open(serv->mBase + WWW_D + resource.c_str(), std::ios::binary);

    if(!fileHandle.is_open())
    {            
        // error handling code
        return -1;
    }

    // send file
    ssize_t buffer_size = 2048;
    char buffer[buffer_size];

    while(!fileHandle.eof())
    {
        fileHandle.read(buffer, buffer_size);

        status = serv->mSock.doSend(buffer, fd);
        if (status == -1)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: socket error, sending file\n";
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

And then elsewhere:

```
int TcpSocket::doSend(const char* message, int fd) const
{
    if (fd == 0)
    {
         fd = mFiledes;
    }

    ssize_t bytesSent = send(fd, message, strlen(message), 0);
    if (bytesSent < 1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As I say, the problem is that when the client requests an image it won't work. I get in std::cerr "Error: socket error sending file"

EDIT : I got it working using the advice in the answer I accepted. For completeness and to help those finding this post I am also posting the final working code.

For sending I decided to use a std::vector rather than a char array. Primarily because I feel it is a more C++ approach and it makes it clear that the data is not a string. This is probably not necessary but a matter of taste. I then counted the bytes read for the stream and passed that over to the send function like this:

```
// send file
std::vector<char> buffer(SEND_BUFFER);
while(!fileHandle.eof())
{
    fileHandle.read(&buffer[0], SEND_BUFFER);
    status = serv->mSock.doSend(&buffer[0], fd, fileHandle.gcount());
    if (status == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: socket error, sending file\n";
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then the actual send function was adapted like this:

```
int TcpSocket::doSend(const char* message, int fd, size_t size) const
{
    if (fd == 0)
    {
        fd = mFiledes;
    }

    ssize_t bytesSent = send(fd, message, size, 0);
    if (bytesSent < 1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should change is the `while (!fileHandle.eof())` loop, because that will not work as you expect it to, in fact it will iterate once too many because the `eof` flag isn't set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file. Instead do e.g. `while (fileHandle.read(...))`.

The second thing you should do is to check how many bytes was actually read from the file, and only send that amount of bytes.

Lastly, you read *binary* data, not text, so you can't use `strlen` on the data you read from the file.

---

A little explanations of the binary file problem: As you should hopefully know, C-style strings (the ones you use `strlen` to get the length of) are terminated by a zero character `'\0'` (in short, a zero byte). Random binary data can contain lots of zero bytes anywhere inside it, and it's a valid byte and doesn't have any special meaning.

When you use `strlen` to get the length of binary data there are two possible problems:

1. There's a zero byte in the middle of the data. This will cause `strlen` to terminate early and return the wrong length.
2. There's *no* zero byte in the data. That will cause `strlen` to go beyond the end of the buffer to look for the zero byte, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I tried using while(fileHandle.read(...)) as suggested but it does not now read the whole file. When I send a text page - it now does not send the final parcel. Also I wonder if you could give some code examples. I relatively new to C++ so may not be taking up the idea as quickly as you may expect! How should I count the bytes I read from the fileHandle for example? Thanks

Comment: @SamRedway I recommend you check out [this excellent reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), and that you take a close look at the [`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) reference, and look for the [`gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) member function.